# How to differentiate two _AppointmentItem?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Is there a way to differentiate two `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._AppointmentItem` ?
as `GlobalAppointmentID` is null when they are just being constructed.

If possible, I'd like to differentiate two `_AppointmentItem` from the same `RecurrencePattern` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to save it to generate the EntryID value.  Am I missing something?

Comment: No, and that's precisely the problem. How would you differentiate two appointments being created ?

Comment: As in if you create two new ones at the same time in two different windows, and don't save either?

Comment: yes exactly. I open two windows to create two new appointments. how to differentiate those ?

Comment: Your best bet is to keep track of every new Inspector window as they open with a managed wrapper collection, using internal properties for every class in the collection to differentiate between multiple items.  You can also look at PR_SEARCH_KEY, which is unique and generated when the items are created.